Где я могу хранить экземпляры Generic типа?
Я хочу, чтобы мой класс мог содержать произвольное число полей специального типа IProperty<T>.
T - уникально для каждого поля.
Какую структуру данных я мог бы использовать? Желательно, оптимизированную на чтение как Dictionary. И без приведения типов/рефлексии (если это возможно).
Отвечу на любые уточняющие вопросы в комментариях.

без приведения скорее всего не получится, потому что IProperty<T> для каждого T - это отдельный тип не связанный с остальными.

@Grundy да я вот тоже думаю, что так не получится, похоже...

Обычно такие вопросы возникают из кривого решения какой-то задачи. Это значит, что исходную задачу нужно решить по-другому. Расскажите нам про неё, и мы что-нибудь придумаем.

@rotabor, с удовольствием. У меня есть объекты - слои как в фотошопе типа View. Мне нужно хранить произвольного типа поля для этого объекта с помощью композиции. У меня должен быть простой способ перечислить все эти поля для каждого View чтобы я мог объединять их в группы и менять те поля, что есть во View группы, меняя поля самой группы.

произвольное число - значит коллекция. Выбирайте любую коллекцию, подходящую по асимптотике. Например, тот же Dictionary. Возможно, понадобится несколько коллекций, для каждого T.

@rotabor например, у меня есть View A и B с полями IProperty<Point2D> Position и View C без этого поля. При объединении всех трёх в группу, я хочу перемещать A и B меняя поле Position группы.

Знакомая система. Это решается наследованием.

Композиция в группы не создаёт проблему ромба смерти как наследование. Все View равнозначны и не состоят друг из друга. Поэтому я пытаюсь применить композицию. Есть ли хорошая архитектура для этой задачи?

Все поля наследуются от IProperty<T1>, IProperty<T2>, IProperty<T3> и т. д.

Скорее всего, вы думаете о глобальном и улетаете куда-то в космос. Ваш код - это обработка определённых структур данных. Структуры данных, для которых у вас в коде нет обработки, в области вашего приложения смысла не имеют.

@rotabor вы скорее всего прочитали о чём я думаю?

А можно для иллюстрации посмотреть код IProperty<T>? К тому же если речь о словаре с ключом типа Type, то для каждого типа может быть только один экземпляр объекта, вас точно устраивает такой расклад? Типы уникальны?

@aepot Да, типы полей уникальны. Внутри 'IProperty' лежит этот метод:
bool TryGetProperty<SubType>([NotNullWhen(true)] out IViewProperty<SubType>? _property); на случай, если свойство - составное.

Я про само свойство, а не про метод получения. Вопрос про ковариантность/контрвариантность интерфейса, есть ли она или возможна ли.

@aepot ковариантность возможна

Ну так и сделайте базовый класс View и коллекцию на его основе. Каждый особенный ViewX будет или его наследником, или с соотвествующим интерфейсом.
Пробегаете по группе - коллекции View, и если объект типа с "IProperty<Point2D> Position", то меняете это свойство.
Если ViewX - это ваши классы, то у вас всё определено в коде. Если вдруг их пользователь конструирует, то без рефлексии или без какого-то описания не обойтись.

Как раз пытаюсь избежать рефлексии для производительности.

Представьте себе, что на событие MoveOn группы вы несколько раз в секунду ищете все поля всех View с помощью рефлексии. Звучит ужасно медленно, не так ли? А это только одно поле из десятков.

Во-первых, я про рефлексию писал только для случая, когда производные объекты - не ваши. Во-вторых, рефлексией нужно пользоваться всего лишь один раз, чтобы изучить тип и сделать для него соответствующий код. А потом просто этот код вызываете, когда нужно.

@Aycon А зачем рефлексия? Это же ваши классы. Ну сделайте там поле HasPosition и проверяйте его. Или сделайте приведение к нужному классу через as и если приведение удалось, получился не null, то вызывайте функцию этого класса. Ну, в общих чертах. Всё решаемо, только определитесь, что вы хотите.

@CrazyElf у меня было впечатление, что это рядовая проблема, я подумал, что может-быть есть общепринятое решение о котором я не знаю

@Aycon Вот тут есть про as https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast очень удобная штука.

Где-то есть вопрос про типы и то как быстро найти, нужно искать.
